# iTunes Connect: Is your app designed to use cryptography?

Tags: encryption, dropbox, app-store-connect, dropbox-api

I am submitting an app that uses the dropbox SDK to upload photos from the iPhone to a specified folder in dropbox. I am stuck on a question as I don;t know how/what/if dropbox sdk uses cyroptograhy. Can you help me answer the following questions?:

Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

If so,
Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?
Make sure that your app meets the criteria of the exemption listed here. You are responsible for the proper classification of your product. Incorrectly classifying your app may lead to you being in violation of U.S. export laws and could make you subject to penalties, including your app being removed from the App Store. Read the FAQ thoroughly before answering the questions.
You can select Yes for question #2 if the encryption of your app is:
(a) Specially designed for medical end-use
(b) Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection
(c) Limited to authentication, digital signature, or the decryption of data or files
(d) Specially designed and limited for banking use or "money transactions"; or
(e) Limited to "fixed" data compression or coding techniques
You can also select Yes if your app meets the descriptions provided in Note 4 for Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations.

If not,
Does your app implement one or more encryption algorithms that are proprietary or yet to be accepted as standard by international standard bodies (such as, the IEEE, IETF, ITU, and so on)?

Etc.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about USA laws and apple policies. This is mostly a legal problem and not a programming problem - ask the dropbox and apple support and/or contact a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

I work for the Dropbox API team. I'm not a lawyer, nor familiar with the App Store process. Presumably it asks this question of everyone submitting an app, and many apps already approved use the Dropbox SDK.

That said, reading through the question ISTM that the Dropbox SDK qualifies under (b) and (c). In the SDK that links with your app we use OAuth and SSL for authentication, SSL for keeping your users' files safe from prying eyes, and either digital signatures or cryptographic hashes to safeguard against data corruption and to detect duplicates.

For more info on this topic see also a recent thread on the Dropbox forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=114805

Comment: The link is dead now.